# JavaScript Debugging Challenge

Tags: javascript

As per the agenda, I should get the following output:

```
Element at 1 popped-out with value 10
Element at 2 popped-out with value 20
Element at 3 popped-out with value 30
Element at 4 popped-out with value 40
Element at 5 popped-out with value 50
```

But, I am getting below output.

```
Element at 1 popped-out with value 10
Element at 2 popped-out with value 20
Element at 3 popped-out with value 30
```

Below is the JavaScript I am trying to debug.

```js
var writeMessage = function(i) {
  return document.write("Element at " + (i + 1) + " popped-out with value " + array.pop() + "<br />");
};
var array = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  writeMessage(i);
}
```

I am trying to debug in chrome. Loop execution is causing little confusing. Can anyone please help me to find where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`pop()` removes the element from the array.

This makes the array shorter.

This makes the value of `length` smaller.

When `i` is 3 you will have removed 3 elements from the array so it is no longer `< array.length`.

Comment: The missing part of explanation (from what I recall) is that JS evaluates loop condition upon every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are shortening the array by popping values off, so array.length changed with each iteration. You can while loop it..

Also, on the first iteration you are sowing the last item.. when `i` is zero you are showing the 6th index, when `i` is 5 you are showing the first index. This is because `pop()` takes the last item off the array, you should be using `shift` instead to take the frst item off the array.

```js
var writeMessage = function(i) {
  return document.write("Element at " + (i) + " popped-out with value " + array.shift() + "<br />");
};
var array = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10], i;
while (i = array.length) {
  writeMessage(i);
}
```

Or you can use the for loop and reference each array index directly instead of altering the array.

```js
var writeMessage = function(i) {
  return document.write("Element at " + (array.length - i) + " popped-out with value " + array[i] + "<br />");
};
var array = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  writeMessage(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `array.pop()` the array size will be decreased by one.
That's the reason why only 3 numbers will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that every time you pop the length of array get shorter by one and at some point(in the middle) the incremented index becomes greater than the length of array.

The iterations look like this

```
Initial state: array.length=5 i=0
1. if(i < array.length) pop & print (value=10)
2. array.length=4 i=1
3. if(i < array.length) pop & print (value=20)
4. array.length=3 i=2
5. if(i < array.length) pop & print (value=30)
6. array.length=2 i=3
7. if(i < array.length) <- here your iteration stops since the condition for the loop is false
```

Answer (score -1):

When `i` is 3 the length of your array is 2 due to `pop()` decreasing its size, meaning the endpoint of your for loop is reached. Store the length in another variable and your code works. Working snippet:

```js
var writeMessage = function(i) {
  return document.write("Element at " + (i + 1) + " popped-out with value " + array.pop() + "<br />");
};
var array = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10];
var l = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  writeMessage(i);
}
```

Comment: And? What did you change? More importantly, **why** did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers. *(not my dv)*

Comment: Pressed the save button too soon, answer has been edited.

Answer (score -1):

Simple logic. I only found, but late. :-(

Below is the logic:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var writeMessage = function (i) {
    return document.write("Element at " + (i + 1) + " popped-out with value " + array.pop() + ". Now, the array length is: " + array.length + "<br />");
};

var array = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10];
for (var i = 0; array.length > 0; i++) {
    writeMessage(i);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```